# GameCenter icon for use in App

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, game-center

I'm searching for an Game Center icon, which I'm free to use in my App. Heard that Apple provides some, but didn't find one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For iOS 7:

[image: iOS7]

---

For iOS 6:

[image: iOS6]

I just found these on apples website. I've use the iOS 7 one before and my app was approved but don't hold me to Apple approving your app using their exact image.

Comment: Link for iOS 7 image is dead :(

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 14 and above it's recommended to use the icons below. To download them as pdf you can visit:
https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/

**Game center**

[image]
**Achievements**

[image]
**Leaderboard**

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to get those icons still? Seems Apple may have removed them? I also can't find them in the latest SF Symbols Beta app

Comment: just follow the link then scroll down until the end you will find Game Center section